# App rotate but rotate option on device is turned off

Tags: android

I have an app project in Android Studio and when I build it and tested on my device  (Note 3) it will rotate if I turned my mobile. But I have this option turn off.
Is there a piece of code what I can use in my project. So that the app will only rotate of the user this turn on on his device?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put in your activity to force portrait:

```
<activity
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
</activity>
```